# powershell csv to json with multiple level of array

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

Currently I am fetching the data from flat CSV and converting it to json. I am able to take it two level down with three Arrays like below

The CSV file contains the following data.
The code I have written to achieve the above is using array,powershell object and convertto-json

```
$ArrayAPPName = @()
$ArrayAPProles = @()
$Arrayserver= @()

$i = 0
foreach ($item in $CSV) {
    if ($i -eq 0) {
        $JSONappname = $($item.'AppName') 
        $JSONapprole = $($item.'ROLE')

    }

    if ($($item.'AppName') -ne $JSONappname) {
        $ArrayAPPName  += [pscustomobject]@{
            AppName = $JSONappname;
            Roles   = $ArrayJSONroles
        }
    }
        $ArrayJSONserver = [pscustomobject]@{
        CPU              = $item.CPU;
        RAM              = ([int]$item.Memory);
        }


    if ($($item.'AppName') -eq $JSONappname) 
    {
        [array]$ArrayJSONroles += [pscustomobject]@{
            Role = $($item.'ROLE');
            Server   = $ArrayJSONserver 
        }
    }
    else {
        [array]$ArrayJSONroles  = [pscustomobject]@{
            Role = $($item.'ROLE');
            Server   = $ArrayJSONserver 
        }
    }  
    $JSONappname = $($item.'AppName')
    $i++
}
$ArrayAPPName  += [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = $JSONappname;
    Roles= $ArrayJSONroles
}

$ArrayAPPName  = [pscustomobject]@{
    Apps = $ArrayAPPName  | Select-Object -Property Name, Roles
}

$ArrayAPPName = $ArrayAPPName | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

However, Now we have situation where for same role we can have multiple 
server request. so for each application name, we can have multiple application
 role and for each application role we can have multiple Server.

```
{
"Apps":  [
                     {
                         "AppName":  "ABC",
                         "Roles":  [
                                       {
                                           "Role":  "App",
                                           "Server":  [
                                                          {
                                                              "CPU":  "2",
                                                              "Memory":  "1024",
                                                          },
                                                          {
                                                              "CPU":  "2",
                                                              "Memory":  "2084",
                                                           }
                                                       ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                     }
                 ]
```

}

Comment: why dont you simply `import-csv` and convert that into json by `convertto-json -depth 5`

Comment: Because I need to create levels based on app name, approle and server list from a flat csv file

Comment: I am not disheartening you,but that can be still handled after conversion. At least you will get a structured json skeleton. Your half of the workload will boil down to couple of lines may be.